# method does not override from its superclass

Tags: java, android

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error:

> method does not override from its superclass

Here is my code:

```
public class NoteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Note> {

public static class ViewHolder{
    TextView title;
    TextView note;
    ImageView noteIcon;
}

public NoteAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Note>notes){
    super(context,0,notes);
}

@Override
public View getview(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    Note note = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
        viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listItemNoteTitle);
        viewHolder.note = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listItemNoteBody);
        viewHolder.noteIcon= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listItemNoteImg);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else { viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag(); }

    viewHolder.title.setText(note.getTitle());
    viewHolder.note.setText(note.getMessage());
    viewHolder.noteIcon.setImageResource(note.getAssociatedDrawable());
    return convertView;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's just a typo: ArrayAdapter has no method named `getview()`. But there is `getView()` with a capital *V*

Comment: This kind of typo is exactly what `@Override` is there to identify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is easy to solve: your method name is `getview` but the method to override from its superclass is `getView` with a capital V.

Comment: How is this different or built on (without representation) from **"
It's just a typo: ArrayAdapter has no method named getview(). But there is getView() with a capital V – 0X0nosugar 
"**

Answer (score 0):

It means that `getview()` is not defined in its superclass. Make sure the spelling is exactly the same (`getview` vs `getView()`) and that you haven't accidentally extended the wrong class somehow.

Comment: How is this different or built on (without representation) from **"
It's just a typo: ArrayAdapter has no method named getview(). But there is getView() with a capital V – 0X0nosugar 
"**